# Adding key to dict to get a dict of dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dict that looks something like

```
{'apples' : 'in_stock', 'bananas' : 'in_stock', 'oranges' : 'not_in_stock'}
```

I want to loop over these and add a price (or any other field). The end goal is to have a count. I'm imagining that the end result would look very much like this.

```
{
 {'apples' : 'in_stock', 'count' : 700}, 
 {'bananas' : 'in_stock', 'count' : 3}, 
 {'oranges' : 'not_in_stock', 'count' : 0}
}
```

I'm having issues adding the key to each initial initial key.

Here's the code that I'm working with to try to get this accomplished.

```
store_dict = {}
my_query = my_sql_query

for item in my_query:
      if item['count'] in store_dict:
        store_dict[item['count']] += 1
      else:
        store_dict[item['count']] = 1
```

Comment: You can't do that the way that you've structured this.

Comment: Your output format is in correct.  Are you wanting an output dictionary or a list of dictionaries?

Comment: `stocks = [{stock: status} for stock, status in original.items()]`

Comment: @Brian, I think a list of dictionaries would be best.

Comment: Show your code and show your issue.

Comment: Shared above, thanks for the tip. I'll make sure to do that next time.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options using list comprehensions and dict comprehensions. Since the format you ask for isn't a valid Python data structure, I present how to create a list and how to create a dict.

```
In [17]: from random import randint
In [18]: from pprint import pprint

In [19]: d = {'apples' : 'in_stock', 'bananas' : 'in_stock', 'oranges' : 'not_in_stock'}

In [20]: l1 = [ { product : stock, 'count' : randint(1,100) if stock == 'in_stock' else 0 } for product, stock in d.items() ]

In [21]: pprint(l1)
[{'apples': 'in_stock', 'count': 56},
 {'count': 0, 'oranges': 'not_in_stock'},
 {'bananas': 'in_stock', 'count': 74}]

In [22]: d1 = { product : { 'stock' : stock, 'count' : randint(1,100) if stock == 'in_stock' else 0 } for product, stock in d.items() }

In [23]: pprint(d1)
{'apples': {'count': 32, 'stock': 'in_stock'},
 'bananas': {'count': 83, 'stock': 'in_stock'},
 'oranges': {'count': 0, 'stock': 'not_in_stock'}}

In [24]:
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this

```
{
 'apples': {'in_stock':True, 'count' : 700},
 'bananas': {'in_stock':True, 'count' : 3},
 'oranges': {'in_stock':False, 'count' : 0}
}
```

is the structure that you're looking for.  To transform your original dict into the one above you'll need have another dictionary to match up the items:

```
original = {'apples' : 'in_stock', 'bananas' : 'in_stock', 'oranges' : 'not_in_stock'}
to_add = {'apples' : 700, 'bananas' : 3, 'oranges' : 0}


ret_dict = {}
for key, item in original.items():
    ret_dict[key] = {
        'in_stock': True if original[key] == 'in_stock' else False,
        'size':to_add[key]
    }


print ret_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through your  code to and build a new dictionary in the correct format

```
d = {'apples' : 'in_stock', 'bananas' : 'in_stock', 'oranges' : 'not_in_stock'}
d2 = []
for key in d.keys():
    d2.append({key = d[key], "count" : 700})
```

You could also choose to use the original dictionary in a different method and build something to the effect of

```
dictionary = {
 "apples" : {"instock" : True, "count": 700},
  "oranges" : {"instock": True, "count": 12}
}
```

This new dictionary could be accessed in the following

```
dictionary["apples"]["count"] = 500
```

Comment: What is `x`?  Do you mean `key`?

Comment: Yes, I have modified the original solution with this fix.